# filter and delete multiple markers in jquery googlemaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using [jQuery Google map script](http://tilotiti.github.io/jQuery-Google-Map/) and i want to delete multiple markers at the same time by a jquery click event.

markers are in an array as below :

```
        var markers = [
                [35.788923, 51.238585, 'دکتر محسن رمضانی', 'تهران دست چپ', 'tehran-umumi' ],
                [35.708923, 51.208585, 'دکتر محسن اسماعیلی', 'تهران دست چپ', 'tehran-umumi' ],
                [35.728923, 51.318585, 'دکتر محسن شجاعی', 'تهران دست چپ', 'tehran-umumi' ],
                [35.728923, 51.318585, 'دکتر محسن محصنی', 'تهران دست چپ', 'tehran-umumi' ],
                [35.798923, 51.398585, 'دکتر محسن علیزاده', 'تهران دست چپ', 'tehran-umumi' ],
                [35.694651, 51.408751, 'دکتر محسن صفانژاد', 'تهران دست چپ', 'tehran-umumi' ],
                [35.7146511, 51.4487517, 'دکتر محسن اکبری', 'تهران دست چپ', 'mashhad-umumi' ],
                [35.6735523, 51.3003982, 'دکتر محسن رستگار', 'تهران دست چپ', 'mashhad-umumi' ],
                [35.6825806, 51.4213503, 'دکتر محسن نژادفلاح', 'تهران دست چپ', 'mashhad-umumi' ],
                [35.7321134, 51.4129257, 'دکتر محسن صابری', 'تهران دست چپ', 'mashhad-umumi' ],
        ];
```

and they'll show in the map with this code :

```
        for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++){

            $("#map").addMarker({
                coords: [ markers[i][0], markers[i][1]], // GPS coords
                title: markers[i][2], // Title
                text: markers[i][3], // HTML content
                id: markers[i][4] // Unique ID for your marker
            });

        }
```

by now everything is OK, but if i want to delete some specific markers using `removeMarker` function, only one markers will be deleted.

```
        //Remover Markers
        $('input#submitSearch').on('click', function(){

            for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {

                $("#map").removeMarker("mashhad-umumi");


            }
        });
```

if i want to delete some markers have `mashhad-umumi` as a filter , what should i code ? Is there a better way doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

**you must check that marker contains your want to delete data look for the title option into your marker and then try to delete that marker**

**Example to use as reference**

```
$('input#submitSearch').on('click', function(){

            for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if(markers[i].title == "mashhad-umumi"){
             $("#map").removeMarker(markers[i][4]);
              }              
            }
        });
```

Comment: not works, because the `removerMarker` function only accepts `ID` of a marker to delete ..., is there any better idea ?

Comment: if i use removeMarker(markers[i][4]), it works but only first element with same id will be deleted, but i want to delete multiple markers

Comment: removeMarker(markers[i][4]) how it deletes only first item?

Comment: it's because of ID behavior, if u want select items with a specific ID , the only first item will be selected, even if u have multiple items with the same id

Comment: so but you have written that each id is unique so how come there will be other markers with same id?